# Installed path of a process in windbg

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, sos

How do I find the installed path of an application from windbg?

Consider, I got a dump . I need to know the installed path of that application from the dump using windbg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entering `lmvm myApp` will display a lot of stuff relevant to your app, the one you want is Image Path e.g.:

```
lmvm myApp
```

outputs

```
....
Image path: C:\AppPath\myApp.exe
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Run lmvm EXENAME.  For instance, if the app is called MyApp.exe, run 'lmvm myapp'.

One of the items that will be printed is the module's path.